# A process serving application pool '{0}' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. How to get crash dump?

Tags: asp.net, iis, crash-dumps

I have a live standalone server running Windows Server 2008 SP2 (64bit) and IIS7. It is running an ASP.NET website built against .NET 3.5 in its own application pool. Randomly at different times of the day, I get the above error. This may occur once per day, or more. Often when it occurs, it will occur two or three times in relatively quick succession.

Looking at processes and logs leading up to the crash there appears to be no real pattern or specific scenario causing it.

From searches, most recommendations appear to be to get a crash dump and analyse it, however I am struggling to get one.

I have Debug Diagnostics 1.2 installed, and have tried various crash rule setups, but they do not create a userdump. Currently I have a 'Crash rule for all IIS/COM+ related processes' with default advanced configuration.

Can anyone suggest why this isn't creating a crash dump when the issue occurs? Is there another way to get a crash dump?

EDIT: I have installed Debugging Tools according to this [useful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53435/getting-iis-worker-process-crash-dumps) and am running ADPlus using this command:

```
ADPlus -crash -pn w3wp.exe -o c:\ADplusCrashDump
```

Hopefully I will get a crash dump when it reoccurs . . .

EDIT 2: Found a recursive method call, which caused a stack overflow in rare circumstances. Hopefully that is problem solved. I found another useful link however, see this [Blog Post](http://blog.whitesites.com/Debugging-Faulting-Application-w3wp-exe-Crashes__634424707278896484_blog.htm).